# nullreferenceexception was unhandled c# error (classes and objects)

Tags: c#, class, object, nullreferenceexception

Here is the error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is my problem: I have 2 classes, Song and CD within CD is an array of Song whenever I try to do access the array of song to set or get a property I get an error.

Here is my CD Class:

```
public class CD
   {
    private string cdtitle;
    private string artist;
    public Song[] songList = new Song[10];
    private int releasedate;

    //constructors
    public CD()
    {
        cdtitle = artist = "";
        releasedate = 2014;
        numCDs = 0;
    }

    public CD(string t, string a)
    {
        cdtitle = t;
        artist = a;
        numCDs = 0;
    }

    //Properties
    public string CDTitle
    {
    get
    {
        return cdtitle;
    }
    set
    {
        cdtitle = value;
    }

    }

    public string CDArtist
    {
        get
        {
            return artist;
        }
        set
        {
            artist = value;
        }

    }

    public int ReleaseDate
    {
        get
        {
            return releasedate;
        }
        set
            {
                releasedate = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is the song Class

```
public class Song
{   //attributes
    private string songtitle;
    private int songlength; //seconds


    //constructors
    //default constructor
    public Song()
    {
        songtitle = "";
        songlength = 0;
    }


    //initialize the song title only
    public Song(string st)
    {
        songtitle = st;
        songlength = 0;
    }
    //initialize the length only
    public Song(int len)
    {
        songtitle = "";
        songlength = len;
    }

    //Properties
    public string SongTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return songtitle;
        }

        set
        {
            songtitle = value;
        }
    }

    public int SongLength
    {

        get
        {
            return songlength;
        }

        set
        {
           songlength = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Whenever I try to access songlist from my cd object I get a nullreferenceexception error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
private void addSongToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string tempTitle;
        int tempLength = 0;
        CD myCD = new CD();

        frmAddSong newSong = new frmAddSong();


        newSong.ShowDialog();

        tempLength = Convert.ToInt32(newSong.txtSongLength.Text);
        tempTitle = newSong.txtSongTitle.Text;

        //index is a form level variable
        myCD.songList[index].SongLength = tempLength;// I get the error here
        myCD.songList[index].SongTitle = tempTitle;// or here

        MessageBox.Show(tempTitle + " " + tempLength.ToString());//Confirmation
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Almost all NullReferenceExceptions are the same. You're trying to access the property of an object that is null (here it's because there's no song in your songList at a certain index). The best course of action would be to set a breakpoint and debug the program to see why the input is null and correct it.

Comment: You need to create a new `Song` object at `myCD.songList[index]` before accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CD class your create an array of sond, but don’t add any Song object in this array. Because your array is empty in this line myCD.songList[index].SongLength = tempLength; your try to get access to unexisting object and call in this object SongLength property. That's why you get error.
To fix it your need first create a song object? and add it into your array in your CD object.

```
Song s = new Song();
myCD.songList[index] = s;
```

After that your can use

```
myCD.songList[index].SongLength = tempLength;
```

Comment: Thank you odpro, something so simple, yet it gave me hours of trouble.